# Printing and saving a web page Using iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I want my WebView to save as image or pdf of any formate,

I tried with saving the web page using the code :

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(WebPage.frame.size);
   [WebPage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

but i'm getting the part which is visible..

i want to know how to get the entire web page image or how the apple people giving the air print so that the entire web page can b printed.. i dont want to know the "AirPrint function" i want to know how to get web page image using the iPhone..

As i'm fresher to iOS development.

can any one help me with he working code of saving web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)printAndSave
{
    webViewHeight = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] integerValue];
    CGRect screenRect = self.myWebView.frame;
    double currentWebViewHeight = webViewHeight;
    while (currentWebViewHeight > 0)
    {
        imageName ++;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
        [self.myWebView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageName]];
        if(currentWebViewHeight < 460)
        {
            CGRect lastImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 457 - currentWebViewHeight, self.myWebView.frame.size.width, currentWebViewHeight);
            CGImageRef lastImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([newImage CGImage], lastImageRect);
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:lastImageRef];
            CGImageRelease(lastImageRef);
        }
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
        [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollBy(0,460);"];
        currentWebViewHeight -= 460;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have 1 doubt.. wen i Scroll down to 2nd page then it will start saving from 2nd page.. and only 1st page will be the problem..

Comment: Where you are writing this method ?

Comment: on click i'm writing this method.. and when i scroll to 2nd page.. it will save the current page n next all pages are proper..

Comment: Keep that in -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView method then see

Comment: its not working in "-(void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView" and "-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView"..

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)printSaveTheWebView:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *viewImage;
    UIScrollView *Scroll_view = webView.scrollView;
    CGRect savedFrame;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(Scroll_view.contentSize);
    {
        CGPoint savedContentOffset = Scroll_view.contentOffset;
        savedFrame = Scroll_view.frame;
        Scroll_view.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        Scroll_view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, Scroll_view.contentSize.width, Scroll_view.contentSize.height);
        [Scroll_view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        Scroll_view.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
        Scroll_view.frame = savedFrame;
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self, nil, nil);
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"view.png"] atomically:YES];    
}
```

**Call this method when you click your button**

Comment: Just see in your home Directory that png will be there.... iphone Simulator --> iOS Version --> YourApplication -- >

Comment: Now check the edited answer and run and see your camera album in simulator or device

Comment: ya thanks it helped me but can i know how to save this image in parts, mean the image is so long.. and i want its to save the next part as another image.. how to do that?

Comment: Means how you want exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

For getting your reqirement you have to change the `context` of the `webview` by changing the frame ,for that take one for loop and loop it according to the number of pages by changing the contex.

[once check this one](http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/making-a-pdf-from-a-uiwebview/)

Comment: thanks : code in this file helped me a little bit.. to get the preview in 2parts.. but how to save that i didn't get..